# Why is there no "mark for upgrade" in Synaptic Package Manager for upgradeable packages?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, upgrade, synaptic

The help docs mention marking for upgrade.  The context menu and menu bar do not have this option listed at all, and the only non-greyed-out options are marking for removal or complete removal.  There are some 40 packages in "Installed (upgradeable)" but there doesn't seem to be any way of actually upgrading them.  This is on Linux Mint 17, 32-bit.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Linux Mint 17 Qiana, [Synaptic "officially" lacks the upgrade feature](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=169573#p872138). This is for sake of stability - users are supposed to use [mintupdate](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/mintupdate) for already-installed packages. Synaptic can still be used to install additional, new packages.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that: I had been a bit confused by there being an Update Manager, a Package Manager, and also a Software Manager in the first place.  I think it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

There is `sudo apt install --only-upgrade [packagenames]` - seems to solve this issue, from the command-line side.

Anyway, it is really sad seeing Synaptic having removed such really relevant features...